# How can I redefine a subfunction of a JAX-jitted function?

Tags: python, jit, jax

I have a function `foo` which is jitted with JAX.  `foo` calls `bar`.

```py
from jax import jit

def bar(x):
  return x ** 2

@jit
def foo(x):
  return 1 + bar(x)

print(f'foo(4) = {foo(4)}')
```

Prints `foo(4) = 17` as expected.

**If I redefine `bar` at runtime, what is the best way to re-jit `foo`?**

Bonus: Is it possible to just tell jax `bar` changed, so that it can re-jit everything dependent upon `bar`?

---

#### Details

If I redefine `bar` and print again,

```py
def bar(x):
  return 2 * x

print(f'foo(4) = {foo(4)}')
```

the output is still `foo(4) = 17`.  Clearly, the old `bar` is still in the jitted `foo`.

In order to get the desired `foo` with updated `bar`, I need to re-jit.  I can do this by rewriting foo, so that it is re-jitted

```py
@jit
def foo(x):
  return 1 + bar(x)

print(f'foo(4) = {foo(4)}')
```

which now prints `foo(4) = 9` as desired.  But rewriting all of `foo` is silly.  I can also get the desired output by just rewrapping `foo` as

```py
foo = jit(foo)
```

But this feels dangerous, since we're passing an already-jitted `foo` into the jit compiler again.  I was surprised to see that it worked, and I suspect weird corner cases with this approach.

Also, both of these approaches require knowing that `foo` called `bar`.  It's trivial in this toy example, but in more complex software, there might be many functions which need to be re-jitted. It's cumbersome to do it individually, and easy to forget some as well.  Hence the 'bonus' part of my question.

The [jit docs](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.jit.html) and [jit caching docs](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jax-101/02-jitting.html#caching) did not answer my question, AFAICT.  Nor did a reasonable search of stackoverflow or the github discussion pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this is not working as expected is because the function is not pure: that is, its output depends not just on the inputs, but also on some global state. JAX transforms like JIT only work correctly for pure functions; see [JAX Sharp Bits: Pure Functions](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#pure-functions) for more discussion of this.

The best way to approach this is probably to change the function's call signature so that all relevant state is explicitly passed to the function. For example, you could pass `bar` explicitly:

```py
from jax import jit
from functools import partial

def bar(x):
  return x ** 2

# Mark `bar` as a static argument: when it changes it will trigger re-compilation
@partial(jit, static_argnames=['bar'])
def foo(x, bar):
  return 1 + bar(x)

print(f'foo(4) = {foo(4, bar)}')
# foo(4) = 17

def bar(x):
  return 2 * x

print(f'foo(4) = {foo(4, bar)}')
# foo(4) = 9
```

Now when you change `bar` the output of the function changes.

Comment: Ah, excellent.  It would not have occurred to me to think of a function definition as program state, but it makes sense when I think like an interpreter instead of a compiler.  Thank you!